# Quick View redirect to single product page not the quick view popup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

can somebody help me how to do it? I need to rewrite some code of quick view i need if somebody push on the quick view icon they got redirected to single product page , not the quick view popup.

[image]

First Step

[image]

Second Step Change to Single of Third Step

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quick view should be in `<a>` tag with the data-target="" in which data-target refers to the modal pop up display.

It should be something like this,

In your `<a>` tag.

```
<a  class="gift" data-toggle="modal" data-title="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" data-content="<?php $content= get_the_content(); $content1=substr($content,0,20); echo wp_strip_all_tags($content1);  echo "...";?>" data-target="#gift_pop" data-price="<?php echo '&euro;'.$product->get_regular_price();?>" data-id="<?php echo $product->get_id();?>" data-image="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID,'medium');?>" data-link="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID,'medium');?>" alt="">
                                               </a>
```

In `<a>` tag itself we should get the data which should be shown in modal popup.

And this is My modal popup html code.

```
<div class="modal" id="gift_pop" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal__content">
                            <div class="modal__wrapper">
                                <a  class="modal__close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/login_close.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                                <div class="product_popup">
                                 <div class="acc_img">
                                          <img id="product_pop" src="">
                                </div>
                                  <div class="acc_text">
                                            <p id="product_title_pop"></p>      
                                            <div class="pro_lrt _fl">
                                            <span id="product_price_pop"></span>
                                            </div> 

                                              <p  id="product_content_pop"></p> 
                                             <a id ="product_link_pop" href="">View Details.</a>
                                       
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The Id of the modal popup should be the **data-target** value.

And finally the script to append the data which we got in `<a>` tag.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //to append values in modal popup
    $(".gift").click(function(){

    var postId = $(this).data('id');
    var image = $(this).data('image');
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var content= $(this).data('content');
    var price= $(this).data('price');       
    var link= $(this).data('link');
    $('#product_pop').attr("src",image);
    $('#product_title_pop').html(title);
    $('#product_content_pop').html(content);
    $('#product_price_pop').html(price);
    $('#product_link_pop').attr("href",link);
    
});
   
</script>
```

And thats it! Enjoy.